# htaccess redirect every subfolder to new folder

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am maybe dumb for not finding the solution. But this is what I want to achieve with 301 redirects:

**Old urls:**

```
/hello/news/news-entry-1/
/hello/news/news-enty-2/
```

**New wanted destination of those urls:**

```
/bye/news/
```

So I want to cut the tail after /news/ and redirect anything after from `/hello/news/*` to `/bye/news/` WITHOUT the tail (e.g. `news-entry-1/`).

So `www.hello.com/hello/news/news-entry-1/` would result in `www.hello.com/bye/news/`

I appreciate any help and sincerely apologize for the question

EDIT: My current .htaccess (I'm on Wordpress):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase / 

RewriteRule ^/?hello/(news)/ /bye/$1/? [L,NC,R=301]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this redirect rule in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?hello/(news)/ /bye/$1/? [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But unfortunately it doesn't work. I includes my whole .htaccess in my post above. Your RewriteRule somehow has no effect at all.

Comment: You need to keep this rule **before other rules**. So place this rule just below `RewriteBase /` line.

Comment: Yeah that was dumb of me. I just figured it out but it still doesn't work. The tail is kept after the rewrite.

Comment: That might be due to your browser cache. There is no way above rule will add trailing part of `/news/` after redirect.

Comment: That could be it. I got it working now based on your response with:
RewriteRule ^/?hello/(news)/ /bye/news/ [L,NC,R=301]